# we are frequently geetting Connection reset Exception in Mule 3.4.2

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule-el, mule-cluster

we are frequently getting Connection reset Exception for Http connector in mule 3.4.2. How to resolve this?

The below is the code which we have used for HTTP connector.

```
<http:connector name="HTTP" cookieSpec="netscape"
    validateConnections="true" sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0"
    receiveBacklog="0" clientSoTimeout="10000" serverSoTimeout="10000"
    socketSoLinger="0" doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS">
    <receiver-threading-profile
        maxThreadsActive="400"
        doThreading="true" poolExhaustedAction="WAIT"></receiver-threading-profile>
    <dispatcher-threading-profile
        maxThreadsActive="400"
        doThreading="true" poolExhaustedAction="WAIT"></dispatcher-threading-profile>
    <service-overrides sessionHandler="org.mule.session.NullSessionHandler" />
</http:connector>
```

Exception which we are getting is :

```
Root Exception stack trace:
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1116)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.readLine(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1413)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:346)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpClientMessageDispatcher.execute(HttpClientMessageDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpClientMessageDispatcher.doSend(HttpClientMessageDispatcher.java:279)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageDispatcher.process(AbstractMessageDispatcher.java:77)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$DispatcherMessageProcessor.process(AbstractConnector.java:2623)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.endpoint.outbound.OutboundResponsePropertiesMessageProcessor.process(OutboundResponsePropertiesMessageProcessor.java:35)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.EndpointTransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor$1.process(EndpointTransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:46)
    at org.mule.processor.EndpointTransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor$1.process(EndpointTransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:43)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalExecutionTemplate.java:65)
    at org.mule.processor.EndpointTransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(EndpointTransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:52)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
```

Comment: Try to capture and share the http request message, both header and payload

Answer (score -1):

You might be hitting the file open limit; a sign of this would be if you see a "Too many files open" error anywhere. Try increasing ulimit of the server.

http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html